# incrementing the digit by 1 in python using isdigit()

Tags: python, regex, string

i understand that by using the following syntax i can remove all the digit appearing in my sentence. How can i modify this to increment the digit or as matter of fact do any operation on it....

```
no_integers = [x for x in list_add_one_city if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```

for example...
given stmt
You would like to eat salad as meal 1 and fruits as meal 2 and pizza as meal 3 in your diet.

need to be translated to (using ISDIGIT()):
You would like to eat salad as meal 2 and fruits as meal 3 and pizza as meal 4 in your diet.

Comment: to be more specific
`def PrintAddOneMealNumSentence(sentence):`
    `list_add_one_meal = sentence.split()`
         `print list_add_one_meal`
         `add_one_integer = [x for x in list_add_one_meal if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]`
         `print add_one_integer`

Comment: I'm still a little confused by what you are exactly trying to do here. Can you post example input and output for `list_add_one_city` and `no_integers`

Comment: please read the above comment. if not i can explain you more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html), the [`.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub) method and a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function.

The regex can easily detects digits, and you can then replace them with the incremented value.

```
import re
s = "You would like to eat salad as meal 1 and fruits as meal 2 and pizza as meal 3 in your diet."

s = re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda match: str(int(match.group()) + 1), s)
print(s)
# You would like to eat salad as meal 2 and fruits as meal 3 and pizza as meal 4 in your diet.
```

If you really need to use `.isdigt()`, you should first `.split()`, the sentence, then iterate through the words list and incremente the value if the element is an actual int. Finally, do not forget to `.join()` the results to get your string back. Somethink like this:

```
words = [str(int(w) + 1) if w.isdigit() else w for w in s.split()]
s = " ".join(words)
```

Comment: i do want to use the "isdigit()" function to achieve.. looking for digit task in my list. and then increment it by 1.

Comment: i do understand, but i am trying to learn use of "isdigit()" function... i just want to go through the list find all the digit and increment by 1.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Delgan is great and words perfectly. I just thought I would add to it as I noticed you are making some mistakes using list comprehension, and I believe this might be the source to your problem.

List comprehension is a great feature to use. But there are a couple parts you should realize. See the picture below to see the parts of list comprehension broken up.

[image]

So when you create a list using another collection. The end part, where you are using an if statement is used for *filtering*, but you actually want everything in the previous list (all the words in the previous sentence) to be in the new list. You only want to increment all numbers in that sentence.

This means you should perform a function on certain elements.  I see in your problem the part of `list comprehension`  to perform a function on certain elements in the `list` (specifically, elements that are positive or negative integers) is what you want. This should be done in the list result field. Here is my example code:

```
# Function acting on all elements, increase integer values otherwise return original string
def increment_if_digit(word):
    if x.isdigit():
        value = int(x)
        value += 1
        return str(value)
    elif x[0] is '-' and x[1:].isdigit():
        value = int(x)
        value += 1
        return str(value)
    else:
        return word

# Example usage
sentence = "You would like to eat salad as meal 1 and fruits as meal 2 and pizza as meal 3 in your diet."
no_integers = [increment_if_digit(x) for x in sentence.split()]
print " ".join(no_integers)
```

which outputs:

```
You would like to eat salad as meal 2 and fruits as meal 3 and pizza as meal 4 in your diet.
```

Comment: I noticed one problem. This increments -3 to -4. Just use -= 1 for that part of the loop and maybe add special if it's a zero to remove "-" from return. This is a little weird because isdigit() but you wanted that :)

Answer (score 0):

The example is much easier with `try` and `except` to catch errors vs trying to build a small parser.

```
>>> stmt='You would like to eat salad as meal 1 and fruits as meal 2 and pizza as meal 3 in your diet'

def incs(word, n):
    try:
        return str(int(word)+n)
    except ValueError:
        return word

>>> ' '.join([incs(w, 1) for w in stmt.split()])       
You would like to eat salad as meal 2 and fruits as meal 3 and pizza as meal 4 in your diet
```